# YES/NO javascript function asking the question even tho it shouldn´t

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

i have this insert form that runs a verification on the name of the server, if there is a server that exist´s with that name it should trigger the javascript function and say "This server already exists, would you like to activate it?" yes/no if yes it does one thing if no it does another, while i was doing tryouts on this i noticed that even when there wasen´t a server with that name it would trigger the event non the less, ill leave here the front end and server-side code, thank you.

```
protected void btn_insert_server_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            
           DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        gridServers.DataSource = dt;
        gridServers.DataBind();

        string ServerName = ServerNameADD.Value.ToString();
           
              dt = da.VerifyServer(ServerName);

              if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
              {
                da.Insert_Server(ServerName);
                dt = da.GetServers();
                gridServers.DataSource = dt;
                gridServers.DataBind();

                string message = "Servidor Inserido com sucesso.";
                string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
                script += message;
                script += "')};";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);

              }
            else
            {
                string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
                if (confirmValue == "Sim")
                {
                    da.UpdateServerToActive(ServerName);
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Servidor Ativado')", true);
                    da.GetServers();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Status do servidor inalterado')", true);
                    da.GetServers();
                }
            }
    }
```

This is Server side coding.

```
<asp:button Text="Insert" runat="server" OnClientClick="Confirm1()" name="txtInsertService" ID="btn_insert_service" OnClick="btn_insert_service_Click" ></asp:button>
```

This is the button that triggers the server side coding and then

```
function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Este Servidor já existe,mas encontra-se desativado,deseja ativa-lo?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Sim";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "Não";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
```

This is the javascript function it self.
If anyone finds out what im doing wrong, let me know.

Comment: One thing to clarify here. You are firing both `JavaScript` and server-side event - `OnClick="btn_insert_service_Click"`. I believe, it should trigger only the `JavaScript` code. Try using `Ajax` call.

Comment: @AT-2017 well i need both of them to trigger no? i want to run the insert into the dataBase but i also need the javaScript code to run so if there is server that as a name that is already in the dataBase it runs the yes no question on if he wants to activa te it. But if you know a way to run both of them serverSide without me needing to use the OnClientClick event please tell me.

Comment: What I can see, even you are trying to validate using `JavaScript`, the server-side event runs as well. The message or value from server-side doesn't match as the `JavaScript` code doesn't have any connection with the server-side. You should try to return the value from server-side to `JavaScript` any way. Are you getting my point?

Comment: @AT-2017 oh i get it now , so its running with no answer is that it? if so what can i do?

Comment: See my answer below and check the link. You'll have an idea.

Comment: I did thank you, @AT-2017 check the comment i left if you can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234158/discussion-between-tiago-and-at-2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the below:

**Backend - Create a web method**:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string GetServerSideValue()
{
    return "Done";
}
```

**Frontend - Use the below `Ajax` call to server-side web method**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Get Value</button>
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        debugger;        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/YourFileName.aspx/GetServerSideValue", //Here you call the method
            data: JSON.stringify({ }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

**N.B**: Please see this for proper `Ajax` call - [Ajax Call with ASP.NET](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

Comment: Where you say here you call the method what do you mean? sorry i dont follow

Comment: The method call is the server-side method. You call this method and return a value to verify in the `JavaScript` code. In the success section of `Ajax` call, you get the value (data) from that method and verify. Does that help?

Comment: I was able to do it in another way, that it just activates the server, since if they are creating one with that name we can just activate it no questions asked, but your answer is great and gave me a different outlook on things ill be reading some ajax docs to know it better